# Unable to switch to pop up despite pop up being present

Tags: python, selenium

Refer to this page:https://www.lanebryant.com/gold-sequin-v-neck-top/prd-358677#color/0000012216

Click on What's my size and you'll get 'get started' button. I am trying to click that but it gives timeout exception.

```
 size = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,

                                                                       "//button[@class='tfc-cfg-next-button tfc-auto-next-button tfc-button tfc-element tfc-click']")))
```

Edit
I have already clicked the popup that the button is in

```
 size = WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,

                                                                     "//a[@class='tfc-popup-click-open']")))


 browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", size)
```

I have tried multiple ways to switch to popup one of which is:

```
       main_page = browser.current_window_handle
        # changing the handles to access login page
        login_page = None
        for handle in browser.window_handles:
            if handle != main_page:
                login_page = handle
        browser.switch_to.window(str(login_page))

        try:
                browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/tfc-button-bar/div/div/tfc-next-button/span/span/button").Enabled
        except:
                pass
```

Still not working

Comment: @Guy my page doesn't have an attribute with iframe that has a name or any other property for that matter. Elaborate

Comment: The pop up with the button does. The all pop up is an iframe.

Comment: <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="" style=""></iframe> @Guy this is what I found

Comment: @Guy how do I reference it?

Comment: Locate the frame weelement and switch to it, just like in the duplicate. You can also switch by index `driver.switch_to.frame(0)`

Comment: iframe is located  using name property

Comment: @Guy you should uncheck the duplicate since it is hindering me from getting the right answer here

Comment: The duplicate is the right answer. You need to switch to the frame and then locate the button.

Comment: As I have already mentioned how do I do that? There is no property to reference it (name, id ,class). Plus I have tried switch to window function and even that is not working :/

Comment: Tried with indexing , isnt working either

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is new like me and can't find the answer. This is the solution:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.tfc-modal-result.tfc-secure.tfc-cfg-core.tfc-language-en.tfc-shopping-for-self.tfc-sfo-disabled.tfc-discovery-disabled.tfc-sfo-unavailable.tfc-discovery-unavailable.tfc-department-adults > div > iframe"))
```

The problem was I couldn't find name or ID or class for iframe to refer to it. It didn't occur to me to just copy css selector directly from Chrome(Click on inspect. Right click and copy>selector)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I just solved the problem:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.lanebryant.com/gold-sequin-v-neck-top/prd-358677#color/0000012216")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='button']/button").click()

driver.refresh()
sizeLink = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a/span[2]/span[2]")))
sizeLink.click()
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[25]/div/iframe")))
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
getStarted = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span/span/button/span")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable,getStarted)
getStarted.click()
```

The first click is to get rid of a country specific popup window which appears in my case.

The Xpath expressions I'm using are relative instead of the absolute XPaths you are using.